# Picture in Picture With WebRTC to Wowza

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, wowza

I have completed the wowza webrtc configuration, now i'm able to publish and play the stream.. what i'm looking is, I want to publish a Single stream which contains 2 Elements to Wowza using WebRTC.

1. Audio and Video of My Webcam
2. Screen capture - Video Only..

It is like over laying Webcam over the Screen or like Picture in Picture.

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting is called "compositing."  While there is no mechanism to do this for you in the browser, what you can do is send both streams and composite them on the server side.  This can be done with `ffmpeg` or `gstreamer` and then republished back to wowza as a single source.

Keep in mind this will add some end-to-end latency to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing that is to use a virtual video mixer driver on your capture computer - such as vMix or Unreal Video Mixer/Switcher DirectShow source filter.
Chrome and Firefox picks up these sources just fine; Edge cannot.